# Android: BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(...).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true) - Приложение вылетает

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-canvas

Есть код, получающий фотографию с камеры:

```
public byte[] i3;
...
Camera i1 = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
Parameters i2 = i1.getParameters();
i2.setPictureSize(...);
i1.setParameters(i2);
i1.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));
i1.startPreview();
i1.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] i1, Camera i2) {
        i3 = i1.clone();
        i2.release();
    }

});
```

И есть код, рисующий на ней надпись:

```
Bitmap i5 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(i3.toByteArray(), 0, i3.toByteArray().length).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas i6 = new Canvas(i5);
...
```

На эмуляторе то всё замечательно работает, как и на моём новом телефоне Android 4.2.2, но на старом телефоне Android 4.0 - нет. Там просто вылетает ошибка

> В приложении ... произошла ошибка

и больше ничего не происходит. Я совершенно весь свой код, всю `Activity` возвёл в блок `try {} catch (Exception e1) {}` - бесполезно. Тогда подключил телефон к компьютеру и по USB-отладке в логах увидел, что вылетает эта строка:

```
Bitmap i5 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(i3.toByteArray(), 0, i3.toByteArray().length).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

Однако я несколько раз убедился, что я так же возвёл её в `try {} catch (Exception e1) {}`. К сожалению, в логах не было написано какое именно исключение вылетело, была просто написана строка, что-то следующего типа:

```
in my.package.MyActivity.Thread.run() on line 67...
```

красным цветом. Впоследствии я выяснил, что проблема в методе `copy(...)`. Если я его убирал, то вылетала уже другая ошибка, сообщающая, что невозможно рисовать на `Canvas`, `Bitmap` которого не `mutable`. Как быть? Помогите исправить ошибку. В интернете подобной проблемы не нашёл.

---

**Примечание.** С первого раза фотография идеально получается и никаких ошибок не возникает. Как только пытаюсь повторно что-то нарисовать уже на второй новой фотографии - приложение вылетает. Может быть проблема в нехватке памяти?

Comment: с какой ошибкой вылетает, где стактрейс ошибки?

Comment: @metalurgus, нет stacktracа в том и странно. Если бы он был, я бы понял хоть какая ошибка вылетает.

Comment: Я все же думаю, что стактрейс есть, но вы его просто не замечаете.

Comment: @metalurgus, нет его. Только одна строка. Погодите 3 минуты я всё-таки ещё раз запущу.

Comment: @metalurgus, `10-10 22:45:05.239: I/dalvikvm(19087):   at my.package.MyActivity$1$1.run(MyActivity.java:140)`. В строке 140 написано `Bitmap i5 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(i3.toByteArray(), 0, i3.toByteArray().length).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);`. **Больше от этого приложения не написано ничего.** Есть только несколько строк, в которых `Activity read to stop... stopping... exit pid...`, то есть лог от самой системы. **Уверен на 100%,** что в этих логах нет важной информации.

Comment: А вы пользуетесь альфой? Попробуйте использовать RGB. Если продержится дольше - точно проблема в памяти. Будете знать точнее где копать.

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii, а если допустим проблема действительно в памяти, то как исправить? Просто заранее спрашиваю. Может уже есть другой способ, не требующий много памяти

Comment: @L'Esperanza картинка на андроиде это всегда проблемы с памятью, особенно на слабых девайсах, почитайте статьи как уменьшать картинки и оптимизировать процесс сохранения фото. Первое с чем вы сталкнетесь, это не использовтаь альфу:) по крайней мере в больших картинках ибо она умножает использование памяти х2.

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii, читал много статей. Уменьшить фотографию, к сожалению, мне нельзя. Размер нужен 2560 / 1620. Телефон Philips Xenium W732. Нужно что-то придумывать. Неужели так всё не продумано в Android, что нельзя элементарно сделать надпись на картинке?

Comment: @metalurgus вы понимаете что каждая ваша фотография занимает 16.2 мб и старый телефон просто не выделяет такой объем памяти для вашего приложения ибо ее использует не только оно. Так же, не ясно зачем вам 2560 / 1620 картинка при разрешении на телефоне 800 x 480. Я вообще не знаю есть ли телефоны с таким огромным разрешением... На сколько я понял у вас все прекрасно пишет на картинке, просто загружая такие гиганские фотографии вы быстро исчерпываете память выделенную приложению и оно падает с OOM.

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii, я понимаю, но это не мой вопрос :-))

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы сделать картинку mutable:

```
bm = bm.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

Но проще вместо вашего примера нарисовать текст или картинку.

```
canvas.drawText
canvas.drawBitmap
```

Comment: Этот код не работает. Я же написал в вопросе. **Он и вылетает.** В этом проблема и заключается. Просто код я чуть-чуть сократил. Найдите строку "И есть код, рисующий на ней надпись:" в моём вопросе и ниже увидите код.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338235/bitmapfactory-decodebytearray-is-returning-null

Comment: Не то. Не `null` возвращается, а IOException, или даже IOError. Я даже не могу сказать, потому что в логах это не написано.

Comment: А сделайте сборку приложения (без лишнего) и выложите куда-то, интересно посмотреть как оно вылетает. Беззвучно приложение вылетает только тогда, когда или вообще система гибнет целиком и тогда ей уже не до вашего приложения, или когда где-то намеренно вызывается выход из него, во всех остальных случаях в логах толстые-претолстые логи. Еще можно повесить хендлер на все ошибки треда через setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() и ловить момент из отдельного класса, сразу записывая результат в файл (доступа к окошкам может в тот момент уже не быть).

Answer (score -1):

Когда-то сталкивался с OutOfMemoryException, которое крашило приложение и её  было тяжело поймать. Суть в том, что Bitmap может быть слишком большим для отрисовки в canvas, поэтому можно попробовать уменьшить его раза в 2 или 4, то есть подогнать под размер экрана.

Comment: К сожалению, это не решает мою проблему. Мне надо обойтись без уменьшения размера.